# Maximize screen size in IE8 using default htm page under MVC2/visual Studio 2008?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have an intranet web site programmed using MVC2/.net 3.5 using VS2008.  One of the (strange) requirements is running the web app in Full screen (so hide all the toolbars stuff).  I have created a default.htm page with javascript which does that and included inside the MVC2 project....and I set the "default page" within Visual Studio 2008 and it runs ok..the trouble is when I deploy to IIS6 it just ignores the "default.htm" page so the web site will not go full screen.

I kind of think it is to do with the default routing..but can I have some advise on how to get over this hurdle?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway got it working by creating a new view page with empty model and change the default route to point to the new page.